# OSX 10.10 locked out of administrator account, not in the sudoers file anymore

Tags: macos, terminal, administrator, sudo, osx-yosemite

It appears my **administrator** account turned into a **regular** account overnight.
**Or**, I did something stupid, which is more reasonable but I can for the life of me not figure out what it is that caused this.

Yesterday I used my laptop on the same account, no indication of any problem.
I noticed something was wrong when I performed the `brew doctor` command as part of my 'homebrew updating' routine: http://pastebin.com/JSn7v0Wv

A lot of dirs that were previously writable aren't anymore.
I can not do anything super user related, as somehow:

```
<username> is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

I can not see which users are in `/private/etc/sudoers`:

```
cat: /private/etc/sudoers: Permission denied
```

In system preferences > users & groups my account shows as 'regular' while it has allways showed as 'administrator' before. I am getting the strong feeling that i'm being hacked out of my own laptop. Only noone could have gained physical access to my laptop. HELP! Is there any way I can restore my administrator rights and find out what happened? I am trying to find out as much as I can without rebooting my laptop.

**[update]** I can not check foor root kits, as `chkrootkit` needs sudo access. `/usr/local/bin/chkrootkit need root privileges` same goes for installing little-snitch :( halp!

Comment: and in the Users&Groups it does not let you making that account Admin? or create NEW admin account?

Comment: nope! you need administrator privileges for that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to get my administrator rights back: I created a new administrator account, using this guide: https://www.personalmacgeniuses.com/2013/10/31/case-of-the-missing-admin-account/#.VW9r9lyqqkp. However, halfway through, `passwd root` did not do anything for some reason. I resorted to executing `rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone` and thus creating a new admin account.

After rebooting, I went to system prefs and changed my previous account back to administrator, logged back in, and I am now in the process of finding out what the hell caused this...